# Know a term to get the parent in Views

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way to use a taxonomy term name to get all the parent terms in Views?

If the taxonomy terms are the following, is there a way to get "one" and "two," given "three"?

- one

  - two
  - - three

Answer (score 2):

taxonomy_get_parents_all will do what you're looking for, but I don't believe it's possible in views. 
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents_all/6

That being said, there's a module that might help you with that. It's called Taxonomy Views Integrator http://drupal.org/project/tvi